# Combine data from two tables side by side in mySql

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql. I have two table `issue_statuses` and `workflows` as shown below

```
issue_statuses=>

    +----+---------------+
    | id |      name     |
    +----+---------------+
    |  1 | New           |
    |  2 | AssignedToFix |
    |  3 | ForReview     |
    |  4 | Resolved      |
    |  5 | Closed        |
    |  6 | Pending       |
    +----+---------------+

workflows=>

    +-----+------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
    | id  | tracker_id | old_status_id | new_status_id | role_id |
    +-----+------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
    | 130 |          1 |             1 |             5 |       5 |
    | 131 |          1 |             2 |             5 |       5 |
    | 132 |          1 |             3 |             4 |       5 |
    | 133 |          1 |             3 |             5 |       5 |
    | 134 |          1 |             4 |             5 |       5 |
    +-----+------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
```

---

**What I need?**
I need to combine the data from two tables like below

```
+----+---------------+---------------+---------+
| id |     name      | new_status_id | role_id |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------+
|  1 | New           | 5             | 5       |
|  2 | AssignedToFix | 5             | 5       |
|  3 | ForReview     | 5,4           | 5       |
|  4 | Resolved      | 5             | 5       |
|  5 | Closed        | null          | null    |
|  6 | Pending       | null          | null    |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------+
```

I need all the records from `issue_statuses` table and matching records from `workflows` table. and if there is multiple values for `new_status_id`, i need to combine the values as comma separated.

---

**What I have done so far?**
I wrote the following query.

```
SELECT 
    i.id, 
    i.name, 
    (select GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(new_status_id)) from bitnami_redmine.workflows where old_status_id= i.id and role_id = 5 and tracker_id=1) as new_status_id,
    w.role_id
FROM
    bitnami_redmine.issue_statuses i
JOIN
    bitnami_redmine.workflows w
ON
    w.old_status_id = i.id
WHERE 
    w.role_id = 5 and w.tracker_id=1;
```

But I didn't get all records from issue_statuses and also the records are repeating. So i put a `distinct` and i eliminate the repeating group. Results are shown below,
[image]
[image]

How can i show all the records from  `issue_statuses`? any and all help is much appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use left join and add w.role_id = 5 and w.tracker_id=1 in on cluase

```
SELECT 
    i.id, 
    i.name, 
    (select GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(new_status_id)) from bitnami_redmine.workflows where old_status_id= i.id and role_id = 5 and tracker_id=1) as new_status_id,
    w.role_id
FROM bitnami_redmine.issue_statuses i
left JOIN bitnami_redmine.workflows w
ON w.old_status_id = i.id
and w.role_id = 5 and w.tracker_id=1;
```